# reduce openssl library size

Tags: windows, gcc, openssl, mingw-w64

Do they exist any options or flags for the config build system to reduce the static library file size (libcrypto and libssl)? I only need the AES implemention (now, the EVP functions).

I am using following flags:

```
./config no-shared no-asm no-shared no-dso no-engine no-stdio no-weak-ssl-ciphers \
    no-comp no-hw no-md2 no-md4 no-mdc2 no-rc5 no-rfc3779 no-whirlpool \
```

Sizes of the generated libraries:

```
libcrypto: 6274kb
libssl: 989kb
```

When I build my application with these libraries (and only using `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()`), I have more than 4000kb, without, less then 200kb for the .exe. What makes the library so big?

Comment: Openssl is a library developed for Linux. Which environment do you use to compile it on Windows? Cygwin? Msys? My guess is that most of the size is required for the Linux compatibility code. Or you should consider to switch to a different library, AES primitives are contained in may libraries. Check e.g the openssl fork BoringSSL, or libsodium.

Comment: I use MSYS64. I know about the tiny implementions, but this is the last way i want to go because openssl is  one of the best supported libraries.

Comment: If you are using static libraries the linker only pulls in what is required when linking your application. So leaving things out won’t help.

Comment: The important think is to have a small end-result: the `.exe` file. You can strip its debugging information using `strip` (or linker flag `-s`). Is there any reason having small static libraries is important to you?